# In the QuickBooks Online API, what is the maximum length of IdType?

Tags: quickbooks-online

In developing an application to sync with QuickBooks Online, we need to store the `Id` of some objects -- Customers, Employees, and so forth. The `Id` is of the type `IdType`, defined in the documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#/IdType

The Id appears to be a simple integer (as a string in XML). However, the documentation does not state this explicitly, nor the maximum possible length of IdType. To store the Id in a database, we need to know the maximum possible length. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I just received a response from Intuit:

> In practice it is an integer. Some products use up to 36 chars. So If
>   you go 50 chars you will be all set.

Hope this info helps others!